# Atiyah Macdonald chapter 1, question 21 iii

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

In a commutative ring $A$ with $1$ having a subset $S$ and some element $x \notin S$,  does there always exist a prime ideal containing $S$ but not $x$? I am trying to solve the $\Rightarrow$ part of (iii). If this is not true always,can you help me figure out a solution? Thanks in advance.

***(Edit) I could not understand the solution given in the link.***

[image: This is question 21 of chapter 1 from Atiyah Mac Donald]

Comment: But that still doesn't answer my initial question.

Comment: True. But I fear you might be having an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Consider $A = \Bbb Z$ and $S = \{4, 6, 8\}$ and $x = 2$, for instance.

Comment: Ok. The thing is I have seen the solution also, but didn't understand. So can you please tell me the solution in a simpler language?